# VUEJS: Model not changing in for loop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

The V-model:"question.answer" is the same for each loop.

The content of rating_questions is:

```js
    rating_question = [
    {
        "id":1,
        "question":"How did you like this?",
        "amount_of_stars":8,
        "answer":0
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "question":"Second question?",
        "amount_of_stars":3,
        "answer":0
    }]
```

When I select an answer for the first question, the answer is saved in `rating_question[0].answer` but if I select an answer for the second question, it is also saved in `rating_question[0].answer` and not in `rating_questions[1].answer` as I would expect.

```html
<template>
    <div class="ratings">
        <div class="rating" v-for="(question, index) in rating_questions">
            <div class="question">
                {{ question.question }}
            </div>

            <div class="answer">
                <div class="rating-stars">
                    <span v-for="i in question.amount_of_stars">
                        <input :id="i" name="rating" v-model="question.answer" type="radio" :value="i" class="radio-btn hide" />
                        <label :for="i" >☆</label>
                    </span>
                    {{ rating_questions[index]['answer'] }}
                    {{index}}
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>  

        </div>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="btn-chat" @click="sendRating">
                Send
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['user', 'event', 'rating_questions'],

        methods: {
            sendRating() {
                this.$emit('ratingsent', {
                    rating_questions: this.rating_questions
                });
            }
        }    
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not in Vue usage but how you use `<input>` and `<label>` HTML elements...

`<input>` `id` and `<label>` `for` attributes are assigned with simple number
`1..question.amount_of_stars`...which means first combo for every question will have `id = 1`, second 2 etc. Moreover you are using same `name` for every combo!

Now if you click on the label (star) in second question, browser just switch active combo on 1st question.

Try this:

```html
<input :id="`rating-${question.id}-${i}`" :name="`rating-${question.id}`" v-model="question.answer" type="radio" :value="i" class="radio-btn hide" />
<label :for="`rating-${question.id}-${i}`" >☆</label>
```

Now:

- every combo in the group (single question) will have **same** `name` (OK!)
- every combo (and it's corresponding label) will have different `id` (OK!)

Also it's usually better to use `:key` together with `v-for`

```js
new Vue({
  data() {
    return {
      rating_questions: [
        {
            "id":1,
            "question":"How did you like this?",
            "amount_of_stars":8,
            "answer":0
        },
        {
            "id":2,
            "question":"Second question?",
            "amount_of_stars":3,
            "answer":0
        }]
    }
  }
}).$mount("#app")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <div class="ratings">
        <div class="rating" v-for="(question, index) in rating_questions" :key="question.id">
            <div class="question">
                {{ question.question }}
            </div>

            <div class="answer">
                <div class="rating-stars">
                    <span v-for="i in question.amount_of_stars">
                        <input :id="`rating-${question.id}-${i}`" :name="`rating-${question.id}`" v-model="question.answer" type="radio" :value="i" class="radio-btn hide" />
                        <label :for="`rating-${question.id}-${i}`" >☆</label>
                    </span>
                    {{ question.answer }}
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>  

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was in my input id's...
Each new question had the same id's.

```
<template>
    <div class="ratings">
        <div class="rating" v-for="(question, index) in rating_questions">
            <div class="question">
                {{ question.question }}
            </div>

            <div class="answer">
                <div class="rating-stars">
                    <span v-for="i in question.amount_of_stars">

                        <input :id="'rating' + index + i" name="rating" v-model="question.answer" type="radio" :value="i" class="radio-btn hide" />
                        <label :for="'rating' + index + i" >☆</label>
                    </span>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>  

        </div>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="btn-chat" @click="sendRating">
                Send
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['user', 'event', 'rating_questions'],

        methods: {
            sendRating() {
                this.$emit('ratingsent', {
                    rating_questions: this.rating_questions
                });
            }
        }    
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

There is very trivial fix of this problem.

See you are modifying the props. In vuejs, props are not supposed to be updated. I hope you might have encountered some error in the console (not sure though, as sometimes in my case also it doesn't appear)

Please use this SFC file

```
<template>
  <div class="ratings">
    <!-- using the data variable rather than props -->
    <div class="rating" v-for="(question, index) in questions" :key="index">
      <div class="question">
        {{ question.question }}
      </div>

      <div class="answer">
        <div class="rating-stars">
          <span v-for="i in question.amount_of_stars" :key="i">
            <input
              :id="i"
              name="rating"
              v-model="question.answer"
              type="radio"
              :value="i"
              class="radio-btn hide"
            />
            <label :for="i">☆</label>
          </span>
          {{ questions[index]["answer"] }}
          {{ index }}
          <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="btn-chat" @click="sendRating">
        Send
      </button>
    </span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["user", "event", "rating_questions"],

  data() {
    return {
      questions: this.rating_questions, // because you can not change props in vuejs
    };
  },
  methods: {
    sendRating() {
      this.$emit("ratingsent", {
        rating_questions: this.questions,
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about the props not being able to be altered, but it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Well that's not exactly true. You should not change the props in the sense you should not do something like this `this.rating_questions = { new object }`. But if you pass an object by a prop, you can change the properties of that object just fine (not saying its a good practice but it's useful if you know what you doing)

Comment: Also by using prop to just initialize `data`, you will loose reactivity. When parent changes value of the prop it is passing to its child, you will see no effect of such change in the child component. That's something you usually **don't want**

Comment: @MichalLevý Do you have a clew what the issue could be? Because indeed rating_questions is inheriting from a parent item which changes constantly... So using props is not my way to go

Comment: What does *rating_questions is inheriting from a parent item which changes constantly* exactly mean? Are you replacing the whole array be different one or are you just adding/removing items from the array?

Comment: I am adding and/or removing items to/from the array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222031/discussion-between-sidney-van-peteghem-and-michal-levy).